# Etymology of "manhole"

Tags: etymology, phrase-meaning, grammatical-gender, gender-neutral

I don't think *man* stands for *male* here, I think it stands for *human*—it is a *humanhole*. Does it have this name because its purpose is to provide access to the sewer for *men*?

[image: Cobbled area with a circular manhole. The cover has a spiderweb like design.]

Comment: There _may_ be some history behind using _man_ in the word manhole, but its usage now is gender neutral (like [man-hours](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-hour)).

Comment: I once heard a wise man say, _Whenever you hear the word "man", you need to remember there are two kinds of "man": there's male man and female man._ That's just a humorous reminder that the word "man" can be used to refer to _adult males, persons in general,_ or _the human race_, as just about [any good dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=man) would confirm.

Comment: [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=manhole) has reänalysed the term into a more masculinely derived sense, but that is obviously a new interpretation on an existing word.

Comment: @tchrist Is that not what we all do to all words at all times?

Comment: I came here after reading [this article](https://www.kron4.com/news/bay-area/no-manpower-berkeley-bans-gender-specific-words-in-code/) .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The origin of “manhole” is indeed [a simple combination of “man” and “hole”](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=manhole). “Hole” is easy enough to understand, but with “man” there's some confusion since the word nowadays refers to a specific gender.

In the OED, we find:

> ### man, n.
>
> **I. A human being (irrespective of [gender] or age).**
>   
> *Man* was considered until the 20th cent. to include women by implication, though referring primarily to [men]. It is now freq. understood to exclude women, and is therefore avoided by many people.
> <sub>Source: [“man, n.1.” *OED Online.* Oxford University Press, March 2014. Web. 14 April 2014.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/113198#eid110473771)</sub>

As is often the case with older senses of words, a sort of [fossilization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossilization_%28linguistics%29) has occurred, whereby the older sense persists in [certain compound words or phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fossil_word). In this particular instance, since the newer sense of that part of the word unneccessarily excludes approximately half of all people, [some consider the word worth changing](https://www.google.com/search?q=gender+neutral+manhole).

From MIT's Editorial Style Guide:

> The *American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language* explains in [a Usage Note](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=man) that the word “man”  has been used in the sense of the broader term “human” since Old English times.  This, the Note goes on,  results in “an asymmetric arrangement that many criticize as sexist.” Although levels of acceptance vary for each of the words in the left-hand column below (as well as for their feminine counterparts, of course), we offer some possible gender-neutral substitutions, should you choose to use them. Which we encourage.
> [table omitted]
> <sub>Source: [*Editorial Style Guide* for The Office of Communications and Donor Relations, MIT](http://web.mit.edu/comdor/editguide/style-matters/gender_neutral.html)</sub>

For “manhole” they offer the alternatives “utility hole” and “sewer hole” which, judging by your question, you may find more accurate to the fact that these service hatches are not actually gender-specific.

Opponents of changing how we refer to “manholes” claim that such alterations to the language are [“political correctness run amok”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3aManhole_cover) and point to lack of prior usage as evidence that nobody will understand anybody inventing new terms for these passages or their coverings. Indeed, despite [increases in usage for various alternatives](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28utility+cover+%2B+service+hatch+%2B+utility+hole+%2B+sewer+hole%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) (which may not even be referring to the same item), the [most popular term by far is still “manhole”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28utility+cover+%2B+service+hatch+%2B+utility+hole+%2B+sewer+hole%29%2Cmanhole&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3). The choice is yours! I personally have no problem understanding when someone says “manholes” and likewise no problem being clear and terse while using other words for these things.

Comment: '"hole through which a person may pass," 1793, from man (n.) + hole (n.)."' All that needs to be said.

Comment: @IllidanS4 You left your answer as a comment! Scroll down to find the “Add Another Answer” button. n.b.: You may need to add more research or commentary for the answer to be considered valuable by the community. Presumably, the person asking the question was already able to perform an internet search for the word's origin and had questions about it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for notifying, but it was deliberate. It would be a poor answer to only cite the contents of the page you linked first.

Comment: Also note that when I answered this question, it resided on [ell.stackexchange.com](http://ell.stackexchange.com), our site for speakers of other languages learning English.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what OP means by "stands for" here - I'm pretty certain non-gender-specific use of the word ***man*** in English predates the very existence of the word ***human***, so we can't really say it's a "short form".

Everything depends on *context*. If a product is described as *man-made*, or a commercial project is costed in *man-years*, this in no way excludes women from being involved. As it says [here...](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/287100.html)

> *Some would argue that any use of the word 'man', e.g. **manhole**, is biased and should be avoided. Others are quite happy with **female chairmen**.*

In short, this whole issue is nothing whatsoever to do with "meaning" as such. It just so happens it's an area of language usage that bothers some people for political/sociological reasons, not semantics.

It's not unknown for people to object to the word *bitch*, for example - simply because they've heard it applied to a woman in a derogatory sense more often than as a neutral reference to a female dog. Sometimes the very same people who argue *for* the *man/woman* distinction feel uncomfortable with the corresponding *dog/bitch* usage. I certainly never heard anyone suggest that a woman priest might wear a ["**bitch collar**."](http://www.jehovahs-witness.net/watchtower/beliefs/121747/1/Clergy-and-Dog-Collars#.U0wCi1VdV2E)

Comment: Well, considering that men are  usually the ones that used this hole , through which they could enter a sewer, a boiler, a drain or any other similar structure, I would say that "man" in the word "manhole" stands for a male person.Words derive from real conditions.





Read more: http://www.answers.com/topic/manhole#ixzz2ysJaXxRL

Comment: @Vic: I think that's slightly ridiculous. Sure, at the time when "manhole" first came into the lexicon, women would be unlikely to use them much. But to suggest that the usage itself was influenced by *gender* (as opposed to the social norms of the time) would be perverse.

Comment: Well, as there is plenty of controversy over female priests, I would bet some would not object to the bitch collar you you mentioned...

Comment: There have always been things named after women, as well as after men, like *ladyfingers* or *old wives' tales*; So I'm not sure you can argue that everything named after a man must be gender-neutral, any more than you can argue things named after women are gender-neutral.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited after comments and answers (to make this answer better and not misleading)**

Agreed, Tyler put a good point. The word *man* has been used for a *human* with no gender specification. **But...**

When these terms were introduced for *those particular work they refer to*, those works were mainly done by men and never by women. Take cleaning through the hole (manhole), constructing the road (men at work), fighting with fire (firemen) and so on.

But then as the world became advanced, women started working everywhere. Let us not forget that our grandma's grandma never did any business nor does they were out in the society dealing with others. Primarily, they handled kids and their homes (Not sure about the rest of the world but this happened in India at least!). The revolution begun and then women started stepping out from their homes and today, you find them everywhere, equally working on the tasks like men.

About the terms, though lately but the change **is** happening. The linguists and grammarians now introducing the words those are epicene especially where things strictly don't belong to **men**. *Mankind* turned *Humankind*, *Businessman* turned *Businessperson* and *Sportsmanship* turned *[Sportspersonship](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sportspersonship).* This is simply because why *mankind*, aren't women part of this?; Why *businessman*, can't a woman do business?; and, why *sportsmanship*, don't women have that spirit? The answers are right there and thus, the terms with epicene words are getting adapted worldwide.

In my opinion, those all work that required endurance, great physical strength and chances of putting life at risks took their term involving *men* and that's the reason I guess, *manhole* is the hole where the person *(of course men, women entering that hole is unlikely even today)*. In coming years, if women start doing this work, I'm pretty sure, it'll be a *humanhole* as it has happened with other terms. While talking about the works that require great physical strength and endurance, I'm **not** talking about the medical condition of undergoing a labor (Thanks, Nico!) but the work that happens in the society.

If there are terms where the word *man* is applied and if these terms refer to the work, event or whatsoever that does not strictly adhere to the gender, in coming years, they'd also likely to get changed. FumbleFingers, the term *manned spaceflight* is already changed into *[human spaceflight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_spaceflight)*. Again, read my opinion above!

All in all, the things those were done mainly, if not only, by *men* once, were introduced with the terms having the word *man* in it. Slowly but steadily, these terms are being replaced if those tasks or whatever is not just limited to men. Examples I already wrote.

Well, the article has good answer, the [article where the picture is probably taken from.](http://inequalitybyinteriordesign.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/whats-in-a-name-the-controversy-over-manholes/) Even if the picture not taken from there, it's worth reading. I searched for the word history and found this what I feel is related:

> [manhole (n)](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/manhole) -  *a hole, usually with a cover, through which a person may enter a sewer, drain, steam boiler, etc., especially one located in a city street.*

What I think is the work that required strength, risk (of life) and endurance were (and are?) mainly done by men. And that goes with the definition of *...through which a person **(generally a man)** may enter a sewer, drain...* However, over the period of time, in such hole a woman might have started working (though I'm not sure for that even today!).

Comment: I fundamentally disagree with this answer, most of which focusses on advancing the idea that we call these things ***manholes*** because *men* (as opposed to *women*) were/are more likely to use them. Vostok 6, for example, is classed as [manned space flight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_spaceflight) regardless of the fact that there were [no male humans on board](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/vostok-6.htm). The actual word ***man*** has always been used in both gender-specific *and* gender-neutral contexts - it doesn't need any of this "revisionist justification".

Comment: Let me paraphrase one of your sentences: a pregnancy and giving birth is a work that requires strength and endurance, puts one's life at risk, and is mainly done by women! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with you, but let's not forget from where Maulik V is writing from and the worldview I suspect he has as a result.

Comment: @Nico yeah but men don't deliver a child. So no question of getting confused. I talked about a physical work and not any medical condition.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you took it other way! I edited my answer and yes, *manned space flight* is already now *human space flight*. That's what exactly I have been telling.

Comment: [This link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_the_workforce#History) in wikipedia gives just a few counter-examples found in history dispelling the myth that women haven't done physical work until modern times. Chances are that many people's gramma's gramma did agricultural work. And although history hasn't been kind to women, there are remarkable examples of powerful women in history: Queen Elizabeth I, just to name one.

Comment: @Nico The Queen is good one. However, exceptions never make rules! :) When I talked about *women* in general, I talk about millions of them in early days, not an exceptional case.

Comment: @Maulik: I don't think you can reasonably say *manned space flight* is already now *human space flight*. It's true the gender-neutral version has been gaining currency, but it's still nowhere near as common as the original ***manned*** among Anglophones in general. And your entire argument that the original usage came about because *male humans* usually did certain things seems like post-hoc justification to me. In such contexts, the verb *to man* has never implied "maleness".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't want to get into the battle of what Anglophones generally speak or practice...because they are the ones who have and will *re-coin(ed)* the terms ;)

Comment: Have women always worked? Or is that a fairly modern phenomenon? That's bound to start an argument unless we first establish what we mean by "work". If _work_ means "toil and complete laborious tasks," then women have **always** worked. If _work_ means "be employed on a company's payroll," then there has been a relatively recent increase of women in the workplace. Truth is, the word _work_ can mean [either one of those](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/work). (Also, yes, language changes and adapts, but I think _sportspersonship_ is carrying it a bit too far.)

Comment: I sincerely hope we aren't going to start calling it a ***humanhole***.  Yikes!

Comment: @snailplane lol, I too hope! But then why no Yikes with a manhole as well ;)

Comment: Because it's lexicalized and no one thinks about the "man" part of it when they use the word.

Comment: According to [Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/man) one of the meanings of "man" is "bipedal primate mammal". Should we rename "manhole" to "bipedalprimatemammalhole"?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion when it comes from if you consider the modern usage of manholes. Today, an alternative name for them is maintenance chamber, so an incorrect assumption could be that the word has come from an abbreviation of maintenance to form man-hole.

Sewer workers or navvy's were primarily men in the 19th century England and a manhole would have been an access point where they could enter. The alternative is an inspection chamber where you cannot access with a man.

Answer (score 0):

The term ["man"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_%28word%29) was once gender neutral. It started acquiring a male connotation in Old English.  However, it can still refer to humans in general, depending on context.

As a general rule, "a man" or "the man" refers to a male adult human.  Just "man" is likely to be gender neutral, meaning "human" or *Homo sapiens*.  (To further illustrate the point, note that *human* is derived from the Proto-Indo-European root that produced *man*, and *Homo* is a Latin cognate of *man*.)

Therefore, considering *manhole* to be a gender-discriminatory term would be political correctness run amok.

Comment: Your parenthetical point is mistaken. It is incorrect to say that English *human* derives from English *man*. It does not, and you confusing Latin origins with Germanic ones. Rather, English *human* derives from French *humain*, cognate with Spanish *humano*, both deriving from the Latin adjective *humanus*, which in turn derives from the 3rd declension masculine noun *homo, hominis*. In contrast, English *man* comes out of a distant Germanic origin. You are going to have to go much further back if you hope to connect the common Germanic *man* to *homo*, and the evidence is disputed.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it have this name because its purpose is to provide access to the sewer for men?

Yes. First recorded in 1769, it was a hole for men to use.

> J. Watt *Letters* 1 May in J. P. Muirhead "Origin & Progress Mechanincal Inventions J. Watt" (1854) I. 57   *I will soon be East, and give directions about the man-hole.*

The noun has survived unchanged in popular use regardless of any modern attempt at equality, which, in terms of your question, is a red herring. From the start, **man**, as in "mankind," was assumed to be males, who, could, at their whim, grant woman/womankind certain privileges such as equality. A lot of this was based on the Bible: 1 Corinthians 11:3 *But I want you to realize that the head of every man is Christ, and the head of the woman is man, and the head of Christ is God.*

In 1796, the entire business of the world was conducted in the masculine and from a masculine point of view* (with the possible exception of any Queen).

Up until relatively recently, the idea of a woman going down a manhole as part of her occupation would have been more than surprising - hence it was understood to referred to males only.

*For historical reasons, all English laws used he, him, and his, but, if I recall correctly, with a rider in the Interpretation Act that "the masculine, unless otherwise stated, shall include the feminine where appropriate."

Comment: Bravo/a! Someone not afraid to say that "man" in "manhole" explicitly refers to the male sex.

Answer (score -1):

English is peppered with words from other languages, French, German, Latin, Greek, Gaelic etc. Man in some contexts comes from the Latin for Hand. Man made means made by hand, a manual is a hand book. Manage is to work by hand. Manpower was what could be achieved by hand work.

Man referring to people has Germanic roots,in German, a person is a Mensch.

Etymology is fascinating and if people would take time to understand the roots of words they might be much less woke.

Comment: You don't actually address the question which is specifically about the etymology of _manhole_.

Comment: Some of your etymologies are incorrect.  *Man-made* and *manpower* do not have any Latin origin.  They're simply *man* (as in, male human) + *power/made*.